# Does the Bluetooth (adapter) require an IP address in a LAN?

Tags: networking, ip, bluetooth

I notice that devices in my LAN that can use Bluetooth all have a MAC address in addition to their wireless MAC address and/ or wired MAC address.

However, I noticed that I never need to configure the IP address for the Bluetooth (although I configure the IP address for all the other devices; I use static IP addressing instead of DHCP for the LAN).

So, does Bluetooth need an IP address like the wired and wireless network adapters? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth devices do not require you to be connected to your LAN, (in fact I don't even know if this is possible) however, because Bluetooth is a "personal wireless network" it still requires your Bluetooth devices to have a MAC address so they can separate themselves from other Bluetooth devices.

At least that is my understanding of the way Bluetooth works...

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth [seems to operate at the lower layers of the OSI Model](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/osi-7-layers-where-does-the-protocol-fit-in.759308/), closer to the physical layer.

Therefore, a Bluetooth device could either have an IP address or not.

The main function of the IP protocol is to find routes across a network of computers, and decide on which wire (or more generally interface) to forward packets to so they can reach the right computer.

In most Bluetooth applications however, say a keyboard, you don't want the device to be able to receive packets from some external device, so IP would not be needed in that case. Your computer can just talk directly to the keyboard and the keyboard can talk back to the computer, and that's it.

The relatively short ranged nature of Bluetooth also limits any potential use case that involves forwarding packets over bluetooth.

A case where IP could be carried over IP is Bluetooth tethering, e.g. this could be used to share the connection of your mobile phone, though I wonder if there's any case where you'd want to use that over Wi-Fi tethering, e.g.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786760/is-it-possible-to-a-establish-a-tcp-ip-connection-over-bluetooth
- https://support.google.com/android/answer/9059108?hl=en

As [mentioned by TheXed](https://superuser.com/a/660758/128124) however, all Bluetooth receivers/transmitters do seem to need a MAC address. According to Wikipedia, MAC addresses are used on several IEEE 802.X standardized technologies, which include Wi-Fi, Ethernet and previously Bluetooth, until the IEEE Bluetooth standard was disbanded in favor of the Bluetooth Special Interest Group, which presumably kept MAC address and maintain uniqueness with the rest of the MAC namespace (?) Related:

- https://www.quora.com/Does-each-Bluetooth-device-has-its-own-unique-MAC-Address-How-can-we-access-it-in-an-app This answer: https://www.quora.com/Does-each-Bluetooth-device-has-its-own-unique-MAC-Address-How-can-we-access-it-in-an-app/answer/Max-Palumbo mentions that Bluetooth supports MAC address randomization now however as a privacy measure, which made the situation more complicated